# .Net 32 bits to 64 bits migration pb?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, 64-bit, x86

I had developed a 32 bits .Net windows application. 
the application had some custom control using images.
When I install it on a 64 bits CPU, all images looks bigger and not on the right position. labels are bigger too.

any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Make sure that there is not a culture setting or system font setting that's different from the other machine..

Comment: Hard to tell without an example of the code that has the described problem

Comment: Check the screen DPI settings in the Control Panel. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller

Answer (score 0):

Images with bigger dimension *should* nothing to do with the not correct dimensioning of the controls. COnsider looking on `Resolution` and other settings of the monitor which can lead your application to not handle resize in correct way. If so, it will mean that there is a bug in your application.

Also considering your question it seems to me that you just deploy your `32bit` application to `64bit` machine, so you, in practice run, by the way, 32 bit version of your application.

If you compile yuor application tageting `64bit` platform and *after* upload to `64bit` OS, there could be potential problems with marshaling if custom controls use `WindowsAPI`. This **could** be a critic part of your application. But what *usually* happens in case of thses kind of problems, is that application crashes, or get **really** wired behavior. IN yuor case, instead, I see that it's just about not correct layout, so most probably it's something related to not correct handling of the resize.

Comment: thank you Paolo Moretti, My setting on the DPI was set to 125 %.